# updating and removing an object from an arrayList with actionListener

Tags: java, user-interface, arraylist, actionlistener

I am creating a program that resembles a student registration system. I am able to add as many students as I want and can find a student by searching for their ID number. But I am stuck on the code for removing and updating the students. Any Suggestions?

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class School implements Serializable
{
    ArrayList<Student>students;
    /**
    Creates an arrayList that holds student objects
    */
    public School()
    {
        students = new ArrayList<Student>();
    }
    /**
    Adds a student to the arrayList
    */
    public void addStudent(Student a)
    {
        students.add(a);
    }
    public String toString()
    {
        String content = "";

        if(!students.isEmpty())
        {
            for(int i = 0; i<students.size(); i++)
            {

                content = content + students.get(i).getID() + " " + students.get(i).getName() + " " + students.get(i).getMajor() + " " + students.get(i).getQPA() + "\n"; 
            } 
        }
        return content;
    }
    public void remove(Student a)
    {
        remove(a);
    }
}
```

---

```
import java.io.Serializable;


/**
This class creates a persistent student object with set parameters.
*/
public class Student implements Serializable
{
    private int studID;
    private String name;
    private String major;
    private double QPA;

    /**
    Creates a student object with an id, name, major, and QPA
    @param aNum as an int
    @param aName as a String
    @param aMajor as a String
    @param aQPA as a double
    */
    public Student(int aNum, String aName, String aMajor, double aQPA)
    {
        studID = aNum;
        name = aName;
        major = aMajor;
        QPA = aQPA;
    }
    /**
    Gets the student's id
    @return studID as an int
    */
    public int getID()
    {
        return studID;
    }
    /**
    Gets the student's name
    @return name as String
    */
    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }
    /**
    Gets the student's major
    @return major as a String
    */
    public String getMajor()
    {
        return major;
    }
    /**
    Gets the student's QPA
    @return QPA as a double
    */
    public double getQPA()
    {
        return QPA;
    }

}
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.JTextField;


public class GUI extends JFrame
{
    private static final int FRAME_WIDTH = 700;
    private static final int FRAME_HEIGHT = 500;
    private JPanel panel;
    private JButton add;
    private JButton remove;
    private JButton update;
    private JButton clear;
    private JLabel Name;
    private JTextField nameField;
    private JLabel Major;
    private JTextField majorField;
    private JLabel ID;
    private JTextField idField;
    private JLabel QPA;
    private JTextField qpaField;
    private JTextArea area;
    private JButton find;
    School firstSchoolOfJava = new School();

    public GUI()
    {

        createButtons();
        createLabel();
        createTextField();
        createPanel();
        setSize(FRAME_WIDTH,FRAME_HEIGHT);
    }
    public void createButtons()
    {

        add = new JButton("Add");
        update = new JButton("Update");
        clear = new JButton("Clear");
        remove= new JButton("Remove");
        find = new JButton("Find");

        class ButtonListener implements ActionListener
           {            
              public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event)
              {

                  Student newStudent = new Student(Integer.parseInt(idField.getText()), nameField.getText(), majorField.getText(), Double.parseDouble(qpaField.getText()));
                  firstSchoolOfJava.addStudent(newStudent);
                  System.out.println(firstSchoolOfJava.toString());     
              }
           }
           ButtonListener listener = new ButtonListener();
           add.addActionListener(listener);

           class ButtonListener1 implements ActionListener
           {

              public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event)
              {
                 if(!firstSchoolOfJava.equals((idField.getText())))
                 {

                 }

              }
           }

           ButtonListener1 listener1 = new ButtonListener1();
           update.addActionListener(listener1);

           class ButtonListener2 implements ActionListener
           {

              public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event)
              {
                 idField.setText(null);
                 nameField.setText(null);
                 majorField.setText(null);
                 qpaField.setText(null);    
              }
           }
           ButtonListener2 listener2 = new ButtonListener2();
           clear.addActionListener(listener2);

           class ButtonListener3 implements ActionListener
           {

              public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event)
              {
                  if(!firstSchoolOfJava.equals(idField.getText()))
                  {

                  }
                  System.out.println(firstSchoolOfJava.toString());
              }
           }
           ButtonListener3 listener3 = new ButtonListener3();
           remove.addActionListener(listener3);

           class ButtonListener4 implements ActionListener
           {

              public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event)
              {
                 if(!firstSchoolOfJava.equals(idField.getText()))
                 {
                     System.out.println("You found the account: " + idField.getText() + nameField.getText() + majorField.getText() + qpaField.getText());
                 }              
              }
           }
           ButtonListener4 listener4 = new ButtonListener4();
           find.addActionListener(listener4);


    }
    public void createLabel()
    {
        Name = new JLabel("Name");
        Major = new JLabel("Major");
        ID = new JLabel("Student ID");
        QPA = new JLabel("QPA");
    }
    public void createTextField()
    {
        final int FIELD_WIDTH = 10;
        nameField = new JTextField(FIELD_WIDTH);
        majorField = new JTextField(FIELD_WIDTH);
        idField = new JTextField(FIELD_WIDTH);
        qpaField = new JTextField(FIELD_WIDTH);
        area = new JTextArea();

    }
    public void createPanel()
    {
        panel = new JPanel();
        panel.add(ID);
        panel.add(idField);
        panel.add(Name);
        panel.add(nameField);
        panel.add(Major);
        panel.add(majorField);
        panel.add(QPA);
        panel.add(qpaField);
        panel.add(add);
        panel.add(remove);
        panel.add(update);
        panel.add(clear);
        panel.add(find);
        panel.add(area);
        add(panel);

    }

}
```

Comment: One suggestion: is the Student's studID  supposed to be unique?  If so, you might simplify things by using a Map<Integer, Student> instead of the ArrayList.

Comment: What supposed to happen in `ActionListener1`? You have no code there?

Comment: ActionListener1 is where the students information gets updated. I'm not even sure where to begin with that code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 public void remove(Student a)
{
    students.remove(a);
}
```

You should remove from `students`. you just have `remove(a)`

You can do this to get the student

```
 public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event)
 {
       if(!firstSchoolOfJava.equals(idField.getText()))
       {
           // input should first be parsed to an int (id type is an int)
           int id = Integer.parseInt(idField.getText());
           Student s;
           for (int i = 0; i < firstChoolOfJava.getStudents().size(); i++){
               // check to see if the ids match. If they do, remove that student
               if ((firstChoolOfJava.getStudents().get(i).getID()) == id) {
                   s = firstChoolOfJava.getStudents().get(i);
                   firstSchoolOfJava.remove(s);  // you're removing this student
                   break;
               }                   
           }
       }
       System.out.println(firstSchoolOfJava.toString());
 }
```

For this code to work You need to have a `getStudents` accessor method in you `School`

```
public ArrayList<Student> getStudents(){
    return students;
}
```

To update a student

```
public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event)
{
    String name = nameField.getText();
    String major = majorField.getText();
    double gpa = Double.parseDouble(gpaField.gtText());
    int id = Integer.parseInt(idField.getText());

    Student s = new Student(id, name, major, gpa); // or whatever your constructor looks like.
    Student s1;
    for (int i = 0; i < firstSchoolOfJava.getStudents().size(); i++){
        s1 = firstSchoolOfJava.getStudents().get(i);
        if (s1.getId() == id){
            firstSchoolOfJava.getStudents().set(i, s);
            break;
        }
    }   
}
```

Note: The above code is considering all fields are filled in correctly. If you just want to update one field where others are empty, you need to do some check to see which fields are empty.

Comment: Which will cause an infinite loop.

Comment: Then what would be the parameter of firstSchoolOfJava.remove() in actionListener3

Comment: class ButtonListener3 implements ActionListener
{
public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent event)
{
if(!firstSchoolOfJava.equals(idField.getText()))
{
firstSchoolOfJava.remove();
}
System.out.println(firstSchoolOfJava.toString());
}
}
ButtonListener3 listener3 = new ButtonListener3();
remove.addActionListener(listener3);

Comment: See my answer. I think that's what you're looking for. You're getting the student by checking the Id. If the id matches, then you pass that student as the argument.

Comment: And I'm not sure I really understand this piece of code `if(!firstSchoolOfJava.equals(idField.getText()))`. It seems like you are check to see if the school equals the id. Is this your intention? Isn't the id field supposed to get the students id?

Comment: yes the code you posted is exactly what i was looking for and it runs the way i want it to. Update is supposed to update a part of the student. for example, change the major or qpa for the student.

Comment: posted some code for update. See the note at bottom of code too.

Comment: the code runs with no errors but it does not update the major or qpa. i tried them separately and entered both at the same time.

Comment: Did you have all four fields filled in?

Comment: yes i made sure i did...i was getting an error for .size() and .get(i) so i added getStudents() before both of them and it took the error away.

Comment: `s1 = s;` should be `firstSchoolOfJava.get(i) = s`. Sorry. Should work now. Let me know.

Comment: `s1 = firstSchoolOfJava.getStudents().get(i);`  and `firstSchoolOfJava.getStudents().get(i);`

Comment: change all of them. `firstSchoolOfJava.get(i)` doesn't return the list. Sorry.

Comment: I keep thinking `firstSchoolOfJava` is the list, but its the school

Comment: still throwing errors on both.
s1 = firstSchoolOfJava.get(i); - The method get(int) is undefined for the type School
firstSchoolOfJava.getStudents().get(i); - The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable

Comment: Take a look at my updated answer. Does you code look like that? Shouldn't be any errors.

Comment: ok i changed both and now have s1 = firstSchoolOfJava.getStudents().get(i) with no error....s = firstSchoolOfJava.getStudents.get(i) in the if statement with no error but still does not update. i can imagine youre as frustrated as i am with this

Comment: Inside the if statement, put `System.out.println(s1.getId())` and `System.out.println(id);` to see if they are the same. Let me know and we'll see from there. Make sure if goes before the `break`.

Comment: Or better yet, put them right before the if statement. If they are not equal, they will still print.

Comment: OK, im really retarded. You need to `set` not `get`.  `firstSchoolOfJava.getStudents().set(i, s);`. I updated the answer.

Comment: and that was it!! thank you so much for your help..certainly would not have finished that without your help

Answer (score 0):

Your question needs to be more clear. Do you want to delete all of the students? Or would you like to delete a student based on an unique student ID? To get you started, here is some basic pseudo code:

```
public boolean removeStudent(int uniqueID)
{
   for(loop thru students)
   { 
     if(listOfStudents.get(i).getId() == uniqueID)
     {
       listOfStudents.remove(i);
       updateView();
       return true;
     }
   }

 return false;
}
```

Also, when you add a student you do the following:

```
 /*
  * Adds a student to the arrayList
  */
  public void addStudent(Student a)
  {
    students.add(a);  <-- You call add() from the ArrayList of students.
  }
```

However, when you remove a student you do the following:

```
public void remove(Student a)
{
    remove(a);  <-- You do not call the ArrayList's remove() method at all. Instead,
                    you call the local remove() method defined in your School class.
}
```

Instead do the following:

```
 public void remove(Student a)
 {
     students.remove(a);  <-- Call the ArrayList's remove() method instead. 
 }
```

Also, what do you mean by update the students? I assume that you mean updating a display or GUI based on the updated student list? Otherwise, I am confused because the ArrayList will 'update' itself whenever a student is added or removed.

```
public void updateStudent(Student student, double GPA, String major)
{
  for(loop thru list of students)
  {
     if(listOfStudents.get(i).equals(student))
     {
       listOfStudents.get(i).setGPA(GPA);
       listOfStudents.get(i).setMajor(major);
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: Okay in that case you need to create accessors and mutators for the students major and gpa. So create a setMajor(String major), and a setGPA(double gpa) in the student class.